# In the Navigator.click() method where exactly in the stack does the scrollIntoView() occur?

Tags: geb

With Geb and WebElement, before a click is performed the webelement is first scrolled into view. I run into a problem here because there is a 'menu' bar at the top of screen that the webdriver doesn't see. this cause chrome to throw a webdriver exception stating that the element is not clickable at point x,y since the webDriver scrolls the element under the menu banner.

If I look at the implementation of the NonEmptyNavigator and subsequently remote webElement, I can't find where the `scrollIntoView()` occurs in the code. I want to put some code in between the `scrollIntoView()` and the actual click action so that I can offset the `ScrollIntoView()` slightly so the click can be performed. where exactly in stack for Navigator.click() does the scrolling into view happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scrolling elements into view before clicking when calling `WebElement.click()` happens inside of the implementation of the method on the browser side so you won't find any reference to scrolling anything into view in Geb or `RemoteWebElement`. Here's a link to an example of the scrolling happening on the browser side from Marionette's (Firefox WebDriver implementation) code base: https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/testing/marionette/interaction.js#148.

If you wish to manually scroll the element into view before clicking on it you might want to write a Geb module and overwrite `click()` in it:

```
class ViewPortOffsetModule extends Module {
    Navigator click() {
        //put your implementation of scrolling the element to view here, most probably using the js executor

        super.click()
    }
}
```

and then in your content definition:

```
static content = {
    elementNeedingOffsetWhenScrollingIntoView { $("#my-element").module(ViewPortOffsetModule) }
}
```

Now, if you correctly implemented scrolling into view in ViewPortOffsetModule, calling `elementNeedingOffsetWhenScrollingIntoView.click()` will scroll the element into view with offset before clicking it.

Comment: Thank you, this question was more a request for information. I was able to solve my issue by overriding the NonEmptyNavigator click() function such that if a webdriver exception is thrown, the test will scroll up a few clicks and attempt again.